# How to convert .csv to .mdb (MS Access) format

Tags: c#, ms-access, csv

I have .csv file with millions of rows, I want to convert this into MS Access format(.MDB), How Can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223685/csv-to-mdb-convertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223685/csv-to-mdb-convertion)

Answer (score 5):

You want to convert .csv to .mdb(Ms access) you have to download CSV to MS Access Converter

from this link - http://www.convert-db.com/csv-to-ms-access.htm

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the CSV data into the access database. I'd suggest the following microsoft link on how to do so:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/import-data-into-an-access-database-HA102840199.aspx